# How can I receive data in real time via serial port in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I am building application to Send/Receive data from/to Hyper Terminal application via com0com virtual serial ports (because I do not have COM ports in my laptop).

I have a form with 2 `buttons` and 2 `textBoxes` and `serialPort1`. When I Click buttonSend it sends the text which is in `textbox1` to HyperTerminal. When I click buttonReceive it displays the text which was sent by the HyperTerminal in `textbox2`.

My code works fine I can send and receive data but only when a button is clicked. I want to receive the data in real time instead of clicking a button to display it in `textbox`, I mean when I type text in HyperTerminal I want it to appear in textbox2. Can you please help me how to achieve that? Thank you.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void buttonReceive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox2.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("timeOut");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [`SerialPort.DataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx) event

Comment: Have you considered using a timer and doing the code if the button on that?

Comment: The easiest and fastest way would be to implement simple method servicing event that Alex K. Listed. Click on his link and read the sample code, it has everything you need

Comment: @ Alex K . still does not work. I participated in the even "mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataR);" and created even handler like this "public void DataR(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)

        {

            textBox2.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        }" and nothing happens when I try to sent data from Hyper terminal to textbox2. please help

Comment: @ CoreMeltdown . still did not work. any idea? Please see my above comment. thank you